# Wordpress passing variable to JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, wordpress

I'm having an issue using a wordpress generated variable in jquery. The wordpress side works fine (i suspect), but in my js i'm not getting there.

You can see the working code here: http://www.gport.nl/dev/pluginshop/gallery/geodata/

I'm passing on a variable like this:

```
$test2[] = array(
    'latitude' => $neg_lat.number_format($lat,6),
    'longitude' => $neg_lng.number_format($lng,6),
    'html' => '<img src='.$thumbnail[0].'/><p>'.$title.'</p>'
);

wp_register_script( 'backend_map_script_geo', ''.WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/magic-gallery/js/frontendmap_geo.js', null, null);
wp_enqueue_script( 'backend_map_script_geo');
wp_localize_script( 'backend_map_script_geo', 'markers', json_encode($test2));
```

and with the following JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var adress_test = jQuery.parseJSON(markers);

    alert(adress_test);
    console.log(adress_test);

    var map2 = jQuery("#testmap");
        map2.gMap({

            markers: [

                adress_test

            ],

        zoom: "fit",
        latitude: "fit",
        longitude: "fit",
        onComplete: function() {
            var center = map2.data('gmap').gmap.getCenter();
        }
    });

});
```

The result i'm getting out of the alert outputs as this:

```
{latitude:59.329500,longitude:18.111167,html:"<img src=http://www.gport.nl/dev/pluginshop/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/IMG_0522-100x100.jpg/><p>IMG_0522</p>"},{latitude:53.197572,longitude:5.797106,html:"<img src=http://www.gport.nl/dev/pluginshop/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/IMAG0183-100x100.jpg/><p>IMAG0183</p>"},{latitude:51.523000,longitude:0.106167,html:"<img src=http://www.gport.nl/dev/pluginshop/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/IMG_0818-100x100.jpg/><p>IMG_0818</p>"},
```

And this is exactly what I need. However, when I use the variable inside `markers:`, it does not work.

When I paste the code that has been alerted in the JS like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var adress_test = backendmapparams;

    alert(adress_test);

    var map2 = jQuery("#testmap");
        map2.gMap({

            markers: [

                {latitude:59.329500,longitude:18.111167,html:"<img src=http://www.gport.nl/dev/pluginshop/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/IMG_0522-100x100.jpg/><p>IMG_0522</p>"},{latitude:53.197572,longitude:5.797106,html:"<img src=http://www.gport.nl/dev/pluginshop/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/IMAG0183-100x100.jpg/><p>IMAG0183</p>"},{latitude:51.523000,longitude:0.106167,html:"<img src=http://www.gport.nl/dev/pluginshop/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/IMG_0818-100x100.jpg/><p>IMG_0818</p>"},

            ],

        zoom: "fit",
        latitude: "fit",
        longitude: "fit",
        onComplete: function() {
            var center = map2.data('gmap').gmap.getCenter();
        }
    });

});
```

Everything works as expected. I figure I'm doing something wrong, but can't seem to figure out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your `adress_test` definitely an `Object`? Try doing `alert(typeof adress_test)`.

Comment: It's still a string, shouldn't `jQuery.parseJSON` take care of this?

Comment: I've got it outputted as an object (the object is shown in console.log), but it still does not work. I've updated my code above. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery.parseJSON` to decode the JSON result (it's just a string when you get it)

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about json_enode at the PHP side? I've tried this and it doesnt make a difference :)

Answer (score 0):

Are your `backendmapparams` enclosed with quotes? `Alert` function would not complain outputing a string, while `markers` would expect and `object`, not a `string`. I'm asking this because if `backendmapparams` was actually an `Object`, you would get `[object Object]` in your alert message, and not

`{latitude:59.329500,longitude:18.111167,html:"<img src=http://www.gport.nl/dev/pluginshop/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/IMG_0522-100x100.jpg/><p>IMG_0522</p>"},{latitude:53.197572,longitude:5.797106,html:"<img src=http://www.gport.nl/dev/pluginshop/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/IMAG0183-100x100.jpg/><p>IMAG0183</p>"},{latitude:51.523000,longitude:0.106167,html:"<img src=http://www.gport.nl/dev/pluginshop/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/IMG_0818-100x100.jpg/><p>IMG_0818</p>"},`

which is a `String`.

Comment: after using dorian's `jQuery.parseJSON(backendmapparams);`, the quotes are gone, but still the code is not functioning as espected. Thanks for the clear explaination though :)

You can check it out here by the way: http://www.gport.nl/dev/pluginshop/gallery/geodata/